# Getting the data from database before running test suites in Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I want to test in Javascript using Mocha.

Approach that I want to use is ->
 - Keep the test cases in Database.
 - Before running the tests fetch the test cases from Database.
 - Generate tests(it functions) dynamically using the data fetched from Database.
 - Execute the tests.

Issue that I'm having is that when and where to make the Database call to fetch the test cases??
This call cannot be in the before hook because it runs before it but not describe. So, test cases need to fetched even before the describe is called.

Please suggest something that will be helpful in implementing the above mentioned approach.

Comment: Can't you just store the test cases as mock data locally and simply import them?

Comment: @Andy -> I want to store the test case in database because if in future new test cases are required to be added then test case can easily be added in database and no code change will be required.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot for implementing this approach and the only valid solution that I have got is using the parameter **delay**.
delay flag can be passed to mocha and you can make mocha wait till the async calls are resolved(for me database calls).
After async calls are resolved, run() function can be called which will start the execution of the tests.